# How can I resize the metadata table on users.php in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've managed to add a bunch of custom forms on a custom login page, and get them to display on the dashboard, but now there are so many the table is cramped. Is there an easy way to enable horizontal scrolling on that table, or something like that, to make it more readable? This is what it looks like at the moment.

[image: User table]

I'm having a hard time researching this because I don't know what to call it other than the 'user table' and that brings up all kinds of database related topics.

Comment: Hopefully you haven't edited the core? Don't edit the core!

Comment: No, function.php is part of theme, you can add extra fields to your registration with update_user_meta, add extra columns with manage_users_columns, and then display information in them with manage_users_custom_column, but for some reason onoe of that actually adjusts the size of the table for the extra fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css file:

```
wp-list-table widefat fixed users{
    width:2000px;
}
```

You might need to adjust how many pixels wide you want that table to be depending on the length of the info.

Comment: That got me on the right track, for sure, what I ended up doing was making it a function in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Adding this function into my functions.php file fixed the issue, and doesn't seem to have broken anything else that I've noticed. The width obviously has to be changed based on how many meta fields are in the table.

```
function fixTable() {
   echo '<style type="text/css">
     .wp-list-table {
     width:2000px;
     }
     </style>';
}

add_action('admin_head', 'fixTable');
```